# Why doesn't lossless cropping exist in iOS on the photos app?

Tags: compression, png, transparency, crop, lossless-compression

When cropping any large image with solid colors, iOS crops images but also makes them more "crusty", or visible jpg compression. (Not lossless)
The original image is from [the Wikipedia page for Nintendo 64,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64) so
I will use the Nintendo 64 logo as an example.

Nintendo 64 image, before crop:
[image: Nintendo 64 image, before crop]

Nintendo 64 image, after crop. Notice the change in quality:
[image: Nintendo 64 image, after crop. Notice the change in quality.]

Nintendo 64 image, after crop, but zoomed in and cropped even more than the second one:
[image: Nintendo 64 image, after crop, but zoomed in and cropped even more than the second one:]

Can anyone explain why this happens, and how?

The latest version of iOS (12) still has this.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate on the difference you see? I don't really notice anything....

Comment: I added another photo for others to see the "crust" more clearly.

Comment: It's simply not Lossless Cropping I guess.

Comment: Are there alternatives then?